# Add external page action link to fb.ui share dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

Using Facebook's now deprecated feed dialog, I used to be able to pass in an actions parameter containing a link to an external URL.

For example:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    href: 'http://www.example.com',
    actions: [{
            name: 'Learn More',
            link: 'http://www.example.com/learn'
        }]
});
```

I now want to use the share dialog, and am using open graph meta properties to customize the content being shared. I've been reading about the open graph action types, but haven't found anything about how to add an action link to the share dialog that simply links to an external page like the example above does. Does anyone know how I could do this? Thanks!